# If statement inside of Makefile to detect docker image exist and if so delete it

Tags: makefile

I have a simple if statement inside of Makefile to say that delete docker image if it exists but it doesn't work. Notice in the log file image exists but when I do `make clean` if statement fails.

```
NAME=program1

all: .docker-build
    docker run ${NAME} make all

.docker-build:
    docker build . -t ${NAME}
    @echo "" > .docker-build

run-%: .docker-build
    docker run ${NAME} make $*

clean:
ifeq ($(docker images -q ${NAME} 2> /dev/null), "")
    docker image rm -f ${NAME}
endif
    @rm -f .docker-build
```

Log (notice image exist but if statement inside of `make clean` fails):

```
➜  dockerfile-test docker images -q program1 2> /dev/null
5ee4797b91ad
➜  dockerfile-test make clean                            
rm -f .docker-build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
ifeq ($(docker images -q ${NAME} 2> /dev/null), "")
```

expands the make variable named `docker images -q program1 2> /dev/null`, which doesn't exist and so expands to the empty string, then it compares it to the two-character string `""` and it never matches.

You probably meant:

```
ifeq ($(shell docker images -q ${NAME} 2> /dev/null),)
```

Comment: I am wondering can you please help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70818008/makefile-variables-dont-get-expanded-correctly