# Makefile: variables don't get expanded correctly

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having a problem with this Makefile structure.

`make commit.install` should create `foo.txt` and then put it into some folder. However, make doesn't call the target that creates `foo.text`. This means I have to call `make foo.txt` to create the file itself and then call `make commit.install` to copy this over. I think there is a problem with make not expanding variable dependencies.

./common.mk

```
src.install: ${INSTALLSRC}
        mkdir -p result
        for f in ${INSTALLSRC}; do \
                cp -a $$f result/.; \
        done

commit.install: src.install
        echo "finished"

clean:
        rm -rf result
```

./inner/nested/GNUmakefile

```
include ../common.mk

include Makefile
```

./inner/nested/Makefile

```
SRC=foo.txt

foo.txt:
        echo "hello world" > foo.txt
```

./inner/common.mk

```
include ../../common.mk

INSTALLSRC=${SRC}
```

[Repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/makefile-hierarchy-issue)

Comment: At a guess I'd say you botched the text format of your question, so that the contents of several files, along with the file names and some other notes, appear as a single garbled text block. And you haven't bothered to prepare a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and I can't tell from your description exactly what happens when you run Make. So I suspect that if I go to the trouble of puzzling all of this out, the result will be a failure to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Beta I updated the question. This repo I linked is the minimal working example. The complete project is very large.

Comment: And where is the working directory? `make commit.install` will not work anywhere in that tree. Voting to close.

Comment: ...Ah, I see, you meant `make -f GNUMakefile commit.install`. I'll try again...

Comment: Here's how to debug this.  Right after the assignment of `INSTALLSRC` (on the next line) add `$(info set INSTALLSRC = $(INSTALLSRC))`.  Right before you use `INSTALLSRC` (on the previous line before the rule) add `$(info using INSTALLSRC = $(INSTALLSRC))`.  Then you'll see that you have not set the variable before you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define `INSTALLSRC` *after* the rule that has it as a prerequisite. So when Make evaluates the prerequisite list, the variable is empty, so Make sees no need to build `foo.txt`. This would have been pretty obvious if you had [simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this collection of makefiles.

The fix is simple; swap the two lines in `inner/common.mk`:

```
INSTALLSRC=${SRC}

include ../../common.mk
```

and GNUMakefile:

```
include Makefile

include ../common.mk
```